# How to define your own terminal tab completions

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion

I've noticed that some programs have their own tab-completion.

For example, git:

```
git checkout
```

allows for tab completion of branch names.

How is this accomplished?

Comment: Also see `/etc/bash_completion` and `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` (or similar locations on your system) for lots of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `compgen` and `complete` (article about [custom bash completing](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/customtab.html)).